# Why the code in thread is not working in ASP.Net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading

```
Thread nwthread = new Thread(() =>
{
    try
    {
        string srch = "http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/" + keyword;
        using (WebClient  webpage = new WebClient())
        {
           // webpage.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent] = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.874.121 Safari/535.2";
            webpage.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)");
          Session["dwnld"]=  downloadedString = webpage.DownloadString(srch);
        }
        
        //downloadedString = client.DownloadString(srch);
    }
    catch (WebException w)
    {
        //Response.Write("<script>alert('Invalid Operation..!')</script>");
        string fpath2 = Server.MapPath(@"~/Ex_Contents/" + _file[0] + "/");
        if (File.Exists(fpath2))
        {
            string[] exfiles1 = Directory.GetFiles(fpath2);
            foreach (string file1 in exfiles1)
            {
                File.Delete(file1);
            }
            return;
        }
    }
});

nwthread.Start();
```

This is the code in main thread of .aspx page. I have written the code for web content extraction in the thread. And session variable is not receiving any value. This is not working without setting the breakpoints.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: You might find this interesting: [Fire and Forget on ASP.NET](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/06/fire-and-forget-on-asp-net.html) by Stephen Cleary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, since you're no longer on the request thread, you can no longer access the request resources!

This includes your use of `Session` and `Server` - both are associated with your current request context. When you put in your breakpoints, the most important thing that happens is that the request thread is *frozen* while you step through the "worker thread" code - so the request context survives longer than your helper thread. Once the request thread finishes, the request is *over*, and the response is already sent - no way to change this. HTTP is a very simple request->response model, there's no place for "Oh, wait, there's a piece of information I forgot to send the last time".

I think you're taking the completely wrong approach here. There's no reason why you have to do everything in a single request - that's what things like AJAX and IFrame are for. It's a separate, asynchronous request - why not make it a separate request?

Comment: So thankful to you...The issue has been resolved when I defined the web content extraction logic in an Async method and awaited in the caller method.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET aplication is an application, which processes requests. UI is drawn by browser. Therefore, there is no UI thread in ASP.NET applications.

IIS gives a separate thread from a thread pool to the every processing request. It means that in ASP.NET you can execute any code, not worrying about how resource consuming it is.

Just remove your `Thread` usage and execute the same code in the current thread :)

Comment: Actually I meant the inherent thread. If I am not putting it in thread, its taking time for getting the response. And finally occurs the web exception.